# Interior point $x$ characterization as sum $x+\epsilon y$

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I need to prove that given $C$, a convex non-empty set:

$\forall y \in C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, \exists \epsilon>0$ | $x + \epsilon y \in C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \implies x \in int C$

Given the definition of interior of a set($\exists r > 0 | B(x,r) \subseteq C \implies x \in intC$), i know that i need to find a ball of radius $r(\epsilon)$, but i'm not being able to write an argument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological vector space (over $\Bbb R$) containing the set $C$. The claim which you need to prove in general is not true. First, you should have “$\forall y\in X$” instead “$\forall y\in C$” (a counterexample is $X=\Bbb R^2$, $C=\Bbb R\times \{0\}$, $x=(0,0)$). Next, very probably $X$ should be finitely dimensional (because for an infinitely dimensional topological vector space the the claim seems to be not true. Maybe even it fails for *each* infinitely dimensional topological vector space). But [if $X$ is finitely dimensional then it is topologically isomorphic to  the space  $\Bbb R^n$ endowed with the standard norm](https://mathoverflow.net/a/50391/43954). So without loss of generality we may suppose that $X=\Bbb R^n$.  Let $e_1,\dots, e_n$ be the standard orts of the space $R^n$. Put $E=\{e_1,\dots,e_n,-e_1,\dots,-e_n\}$. Since the set $E$ is finite then there exists $\epsilon>0 $ such that $x+\varepsilon y\in C$ for each $y\in E$. Since the set $C$ is convex, $x+\epsilon\operatorname{conv} E\subset C$. Using the inequality between the arithmetic and quadratic means, we can easily show that $\operatorname{conv} E\supset B(0,\epsilon/\sqrt{n})$. Thus $x+B(0,\epsilon/\sqrt{n})\subset C$, so $x\in\operatorname{int} C$.

Comment: The statement is true if $X$ is a Banach space and $C$ is assumed to be closed. Otherwise it will fail in infinite dimensions: take a linear, discontinuous functional $\varphi$ on $X$ and consider the set $\{x \in X : \lvert \varphi(x) \rvert \le 1\}$.

Comment: $X$ is finitely dimensional. I forgot to mention that. Thanks